# How to convert Python / Kivy program from using X11 to using framebuffer (from Window to Kiosk operation)

Tags: python, kivy, kiosk

I am running a [Python](https://www.python.org/) program using [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) to create the program's GUI.  This works as expected when the program is running on a Desktop on an X11 server.  However I want to convert the Python / Kivy program into a stand alone application.  A Kiosk application.  Instead of running a Desktop and X11 server, I want to convert the Python / Kivy program to write directly to the FramBuffer.  This is talked about [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.fbo.html) in on the Kivy web site.   But this does not appear to be a fully functional example program.  Any help in explaining how to use the information on this web page or identifying a working Kivy / FrameBuffer project I can inspect would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are ok with keeping X11, but just don't want a window manager, [consider reading this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-x-applications-without-a-desktop-or-a-wm).

Comment: I have been able to start the application using this technique directly from the command line.  When the application exits I return to the command line.  This is the desired behavior.  However, I have lost the screen rotation I had configured using the rasp-config.  I'll have to determine what file rasp-config changes and why that is not picked up by the instance of X11 started along w/our application.

Comment: Big thread [on that issue here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=197122).

Comment: I can't edit my comment.  But should correct what I said.  The screen rotation was obtained by a Desktop menu, not raspi-config.  I want to say this is new to the Raspberry Pi 4.

Answer (score 1):

Kivy doesn't support rendering directly to a linux framebuffer. The fbo documentation you have found is for opengl framebuffer objects.

The exception is for the raspberry pi, on which we supports its particular EGL implementation.

It should be technically possible to support rendering without X, but you'd likely need to write a new Window backend implementing this by setting up the framebuffer to display opengl. I've never seen anyone successfully do this so there are likely no examples.

It's likely to be more straightforward to use a minimal X11 kiosk, or a wayland kiosk may be more lightweight and should work fine.

Comment: Hi @inclement.  I actually am using a Raspberry Pi.  So this EGL implementation interests me.  Is [this web page](https://jan.newmarch.name/RPi/EGL/) a good resource to learn about EGL on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I don't know, but in that case you definitely want to use the rpi window backend. I remember something was different on the newest rpi version but I don't think it affects that.